# Android ListFragment onListItemClick handling

Tags: android, json, android-listfragment, onitemclicklistener

I am newer to Android and apologize for sounding so. The code would add little value so in short, I have a listfragment that pulls JSON to form the views. I simply wish to add methods/code so that onListItemClick will display a detailed view of the the list item as well as other information.

Does the implementation require placing the separate list items into respective objects so the data can be pulled and organized post item click?

I know this seems fairly straightforward, but I have yet to find a decent source/tutorial on how to do this. Any insight would be welcomed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Example code for creating list of objects from JsonArray.

```
ArrayList<MyObject> myList = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

public void parseJsonObjectIntoStorage(JsonArray data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
        JsonObject jsonObject = data.get(i).getAsJsonObject();
        // Your class should have a constructor that accepts a JsonObject
        // and constructs your object with GSON
        MyObject obj = new MyObject(jsonObject);
        myList.add(obj);
    }
}
```

---

First, you will need to parse the JSON into objects, which can be put into a list to feed into your adapter. I recommend [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) for taking care of this.

Here's a great [tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) for using ListViews. It also describes [ExpandableListViews](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html), which if I understand your question, is what you are looking for.

Comment: I'm sorry, it's not expandable views but an actual click through, to a detailed view. Think as in the YouTube app, there is a list of videos, one can then click through and view content, comments and video related to that video specifically,.

Comment: Ok, this is simpler then. Use a regular ListView per the tutorial above. When the item is clicked, launch a new activity and pass the object associated with the selected row into the new activity.

Comment: How can you handle multiple JSON object in GSON? Do I create a new GSON object for each JSON object? The tutorial did not focus on a string of JSON objects, say a case with 50+

Comment: Might want to do `myList.add(new MyObject(jsonObject));` instead. One statement, instead of two.

Comment: @MikeOrtiz, how would the constructor in the `MyObject` class look?

Comment: Can GSON serialize a whole JsonArray into a List, so you can do `myList.addAll` instead of `myList.add`?